# Python filter function - if a word in a list starts with a specific character

Tags: python, list, function

My list:

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great', 'salami']
```

I am trying to create a new list that only contains the words whose starting character is 's'.

My attempt:

```
def check_letter(input_list):
    if input_list[0].lower() == 's':
        return True
    else:
        return False

filtered_list = filter(check_letter, seq)
print(filtered_list)
```

what I get as the output is:

```
<filter object at 0x10e3f6f98>
```

What I am expecting is:

```
['soup', 'salad', 'salami']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try this print(list(filtered_list))

Comment: filter in python 3 returns a generator. you need to iterate it to get a list (or cast it to a list ... which will iterate it)

Comment: Short form of `check_letter`: `def check_letter(word): return word[0].lower() == 's'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns generator object in python3, so either iterate it or to get list use in-built list function:

```
print(list(filtered_list))
```

**Output:**

```
['soup', 'salad', 'salami']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension too.

```
In [1]: seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great', 'salami']

In [2]: out = [x for x in seq if x.lower().startswith('s')]

In [3]: out
Out[3]: ['soup', 'salad', 'salami']
```